# C Unix/Linux programming: Which type is md_addr_t?

Tags: c, linux

`GCC` gives me the following:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘_panic’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type

misc.h:191: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
```

The second argument is of type `md_addr_t`. How can I cast this to `char*` and what does `md_addr_t` meant to be? (Neither man-page could help me nor google)

Comment: Let us see some code and give use more information about the case

Comment: The case is that i want to build simplescalarsimulator power-pc target (http://www.simplescalar.com/v4test.html) for Linux/x86. I steped through the Linux section in this short tutorial: http://www.cs.unm.edu/~qfduan/cs/thesisnotes.txt
But if i do 'make' i get the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason has been pointed out by larsmans correctly. This warning is seen when casting `const` away i.e. if a function take `non-const` argument but you pass `const` argument, then if the function modifies the argument passed you have undefined behaviour. `md_addr_t` which is typedef in the code has nothing to do with this. In the code you are getting these warning on using `panic` which is defined as follows (source from ss-ppc-little.tgz in your link):

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
/* declare a panic situation, dumps core */
#define panic(fmt, args...)     \
  _panic(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, fmt, ## args)

void
_panic(char *file, char *func, int line, char *fmt, ...)
__attribute__ ((noreturn));
#else /* !__GNUC__ */
void 
panic(char *fmt, ...);
#endif /* !__GNUC__ */
```

On Unix/Linux system `__GNUC__` is defined thus the first definition is used in which you are pre pending file name (`__FILE__`), function name (`__FUNCTION__`) & line number (`__LINE__`) before printing out the message. (See [this link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) for details).Here as you can see  `_panic` expects `char*` as first & second arguments but arguments being passed are `__FILE__` & `__FUNCTION__` where [`__FUNCTION__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) is `static const char[]`.  You can change  `_panic(char *file, char *func, int line, char *fmt, ...)` to `_panic(char *file, const char func[], int line, char *fmt, ...)` or to `_panic(char *file, const char *func, int line, char *fmt, ...)` - as the compiler is complaining fix your warning. As`__FILE__` is also constant you can consider changing to `_panic(const char *file, const char *func, int line, char *fmt, ...)`
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`grep -R md_addr_t /usr/include` does not return anything in a well-populated `/usr/include`, nor does it ring a bell. It must be something in your application/library.

In any case, casting to `char *`  is just a matter of prefixing `(char *)`, which is also one of the few casts that are guaranteed to always work in C, although casting `const` away might mean that someone is going to write to read-only memory, which is not guaranteed to work...